# Unable to reset orient-db password

Tags: database, orientdb

I have recently started learning orient-db but some how forgot the root password I set in the very beginning of installation. Can someone please tell how to reset it. I have googled a lot and looked through the documentation as well but nothing worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Server users are stored in the config/orientdb-server-config.xml configuration file, in the  element.

```
  <users>
        <user resources="*" password="{PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256} YOUR PASSWORD" name="root"/>
        <user resources="connect,server.listDatabases,server.dblist" password="{PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256} YOUR PASSWORD" name="guest"/>
    </users>
```

If you want to reset the password you have to delete the two lines that i posted above and set to false this parameter:

```
<isAfterFirstTime>false</isAfterFirstTime>
```

Hope it helps.

Regards

Comment: doesn't work for me. v2.2 on mac os x installed via brew. after start and stop orientdb the users are appears in config without asking any password